# What are my free and/or open source options for decompiling class files and JARs?

Tags: java, decompiling, jad

I'm familiar with [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)), and haven't found anything newer or better, but I really didn't look that hard because I had previous experience with the JAD tool. However, I might have missed some really good options out there. Did I miss anything good? If so, what is it and what features does it have in comparison to JAD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used Jad, but there's also a decompiler called **DJ** that you may want to take a look at:

http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html

It has it's own GUI as well.  Looks ok.

From Java 5 upwards there's also **javap** which dissassemble classfiles:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html

Answer (score 1):

I like [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Comment: JD has a restrictive license that makes it impractical for some purposes, although it does look solid for individuals producing non-commercial code.

Comment: Seems to work, and has a Linux version too!

Comment: Hi,
I put online 6 Java decompilers: Jadx, fast and with Android support, CFR (supports Java 8),  JDCore (very fast), Procyon,  Fernflower and JAD (very fast, but outdated). All of them (excluding JAD) are open-source.

One may use them without installation here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/